# How do I optimize this sql with a lot of functions and group by?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

I have the following sql, and I want to return `gene_info` from `sample_info`, `id_card_no` from `person_info`, `race` from `person_info` and `gene_info` from `sample_dna_gene`.

Foreign keys: `person_info.id` = `sample_info.self_object_id` and `sample_info.id` = `sample_dng_gene.sample_id`

I'm taking the first of `id` from `sample_info` and first of `gene_info` from `sample_dna_gene`, so I need to use group by likely and I don't see other ways to do this. I also need to add max() for other columns. This looks inefficient and I want to see if there are other ways to do this. The database has up to a billion records, so speed is important.

```
select to_char(sdg.gene_info), max(aa.pid), max(aa.idn), max(aa.r)
      from (select max(pi.person_name),
                   max(pi.id) pid,
                   si.id sid,
                   max(pi.id_card_no) idn,
                   max(pi.race) r
              from person_info pi
              join sample_info si
                on pi.id = si.self_object_id
             group by si.id) aa
      join sample_dna_gene sdg
        on sdg.sample_id = aa.sid
     where aa.pid in ('...')
     group by to_char(sdg.gene_info)
```

Comment: "This looks inefficient" Does the execution plan agree?

Comment: I haven't tested it with the real database yet. I'm writing a program in java with a test database holding only a few hundreds records.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing is you need to restrict the set of persons you retrieve as soon as possible. This means the `where aa.pid in (...)` really ought to be `where pi.id in  ('...')`.

Secondly, there should be a more efficient way of restricting the set of `sample_info` records. Preferably there should be some business logic (sample date? status?). But you can use an analytic function to just get the earliest.

Really not sure why you have the GROUP BY in the outer query. All those `MAX()` calls won't change the result set. It's just a needless waste of cycles.

```
with aa as (
    select pi.person_name
           , pi.id as pid
           , pi.id_card_no
           , pi.race
           , si.id as sid
           , row_number() over (partition by pi.id order by si.self_object_id ) as rn
    from person_info pi
         join sample_info si
             on pi.id = si.self_object_id
   where pi.id in  ('...')
 )
select aa.pid
      , aa.person_name
      , aa.race
      , aa.id_card_no
      , sdg.gene_info
from aa
join sample_dna_gene sdg
    on sdg.sample_id = aa.sid
where aa.rn = 1 -- just get the first matched `sample_info.id` for each `person_info`.
```

The one snag is that injecting a list of values - `pi.id in  ('...')` - into a subquery is easy when writing SQL, but harder when calling that SQL through frameworks like Spring. However, you should focus on getting the SQL correct first, then worry about how to run it.